# Eclipse - Theme.res not found - IOException of the Java Simulator

Tags: codenameone

After building my app for iOS, the simulator keep throwing my an IOException with this description:
/theme.res not found
I already tried to rebuild the project,refresh,moving theme.res on the root (/),moving it in the package again, but I still get this error.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

theme.res should be in the src directory not within a package.

If you open it in the designer do you have a theme within it? Make sure it has a valid theme.

I would also suggest stating the IDE you used for reference.

Comment: Yes, the designed have a theme in it.And the IDE is Eclipse.Anyway still not solving the problem :(

Comment: try to recreate the project and do a 'F5' on the project just after creation